# TFS 2017 Build Definition with .NET 4.6 and ASP.NET Core

Tags: tfs, build, asp.net-core, msbuild, build-definition

I'm trying to create a build definition in TFS for a solution with both Windows client .NET 4.6 libraries and an ASP.NET Core web project.  Currently when I try to run the NuGet Restore portion of the build I get the following error message.

> WebApplication.csproj(1,1): error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

The error occurs when trying to restore the NuGet packages on the ASP.NET Core project.

Everything builds fine on my local development environment, its just the build definition that isn't working.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually pointing to Nuget 4.1 instead of the built-in 3.5 resolved the issue.